# What is the correct gravity for white wine?

Tags: wine, kits, youngs

Bought a Youngs u Brew 7 Day wine kit. Similar to this: https://www.thehomebrewcompany.ie/winebuddy-sauvignon-blanc-30-bottles-p-532.html

The instructions says that I should only bottle when the gravity is between 1.006 and 1.000. However, after the 6 days as stated in the instructions I tested my gravity only to find that its at 1.032. So that is a massive difference. I'm guessing the yeast didn't do it's job.

Temperature was about right the entire time. Had a belt around the demijon at time to ensure it stayed around 22 degrees.

There was excessive foaming at one stage, so I am wondering if that affected the wine in some way?

So is there a correct gravity for wine at this stage? If so, am I completely off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing you can do now is wait. Chances are the yeast are still actively metabolizing sugars, albeit a bit slower than earlier in the fermentation. Check it in a week, and if the gravity hasn't dropped significantly, consider pitching a fresh packet of yeast.

What you don't want to do is bottle the wine now. If fermentation is, as I suspect, continuing, the bottles will end up exploding or blowing their corks. Yeast produces CO<sub>2</sub> as well as alcohol, which, if confined, can create massive pressures.

Even though the kit you used is sold as a 7-day kit, the wine will taste *much* better if you let it age some. Personally, I don't drink a wine until it's aged at least a year. Your patience may not extend that far, but if you can give it 3 or 4 months you'll be rewarded with a much tastier drink.

Comment: I think you are right. I see some life in it now. The yeast must have just gone dormant or something because its back frothing now. I'll leave it for a another while and test the gravity again. Hopefully it will be better. Thanks!